# Applying font with emojis only

Tags: css, fonts

Basically I will make a font with some unicode characters. (not all) How do I apply it so that it will only apply on emojis?

Using unicode ranges will solve my problem, but will create another one. It takes the fonts for all other unicode characters away and replaces it with the default one. Is there any way to avoid this as well?

Thanks.

**Edit 1**
I also want to do this for input areas, so span shouldn't work..

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it's hard to believe. You can wrap the emojis with `span` and set the `font-family` to the emojis font.

Comment: Do i really need to use that? There will be much html in my databases. Is there any other way to do this? I've already thought about this, but I don't really think using a for loop and replacing every emoji from a list which has 2260 emojis will still maintain performance.

Comment: This is my opinion. Of course I may wrong :)

Comment: It seems that kind of thing already done. For example: http://crocodillon.com/blog/parsing-emoji-unicode-in-javascript, https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-parser